# Adding Facebook IPv6 to Centos, getting CurlException 7

Tags: iptables, centos5, ipv6

I'm correctly get following error. After searching about this issue, correct me if i'm wrong, I believe that adding/configuring IPv6 should solve the problem.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:8f02:face:b00c:0:26: Network is unreachable\n  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/facedex.net/httpdocs/fb/apps/seemyfuture/src/base_facebook.php on line 886
```

The problem is I dont know the right way to add it. There seems to have may methods.
    http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/x1035.html#AEN1044
    https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34093/static-ipv4-ipv6-configuration-on-centos-6-2

My netstat show this. Shell doesnt recogize -rn6 though.It shows invalid option -- 6

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
27.254.38.128   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         27.254.38.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

FYI: I'm using Centos 5.7.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you show your IPv6 route table? `netstat -rn6`

Comment: netstat -rn6 shows invalid option -- 6 so i put -rn instead. Above is the output. Not sure this is what you want to see

Comment: How about `/sbin/ip -f inet6 route show`? You'll need the iproute2 package installed. If this still has no output then mgroven is right.

Comment: f e80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256  expires 21110466sec mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295 Does this mean anything?

Comment: It means you don't have an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't actually have IPv6 connectivity, in which case you probably want to [disable IPv6](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS5#head-47912ebdae3b5ac10ff76053ef057c366b421dc4).

Answer (score 1):

Short of globally disabling ipv6 you can try the --ipv4 argument to curl. I think that is what I used in a similar situation.

Comment: Sorry. How can i do that? i dont know much about server

Answer (score 0):

You can't just arbitrarily configure IPv6. You need to get IPv6 from your **ISP**, or create a tunnel with **Hurricane Electric**, **Gogo6** or similar.